# Kubectl: jsonpath works but custom-column doesn't

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Consider following expression

```
kubectl get deploy -o 'jsonpath={.items[*].apiVersion}'
```

It returns following output:

```
apps/v1 apps/v1
```

When using exactly the same expression with custom-columns:

```
kubectl get deploy -o 'custom-columns=A:{.items[*].apiVersion}'
```

I get:

```
A
<none>
<none>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the case you are testing is kind of misleading. Because both `Deployment` and `DeploymentList` have the same apiVersion (`apps/v1`).
So let's work on `.metadata.name` for example:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get deploy -o 'jsonpath={.items[*].metadata.name}'
```

You will get a result like this:

```
calico-kube-controllers coredns dns-autoscaler kubernetes-dashboard metrics-server rbd-provisioner
```

But for custom column it is somehow different. Table is for showing a list of content. So the path you provide is for each row of the table. so you should use:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get deploy -o 'custom-columns=A:{.metadata.name}'
```

And you will get the correct result:

```
A
calico-kube-controllers
coredns
dns-autoscaler
kubernetes-dashboard
metrics-server
rbd-provisioner
```

So the problem was with using `items[*]` on `custom-columns`.

Answer (score 1):

For the custom-columns you have to use the below way.

`kubectl get deploy -o 'custom-columns=A:{.apiVersion}'`

And you should see output like below if you have deployments 1 or more.

```
A
apps/v1
apps/v1
```